# Add User in my Android app

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

Hi I Implemented an android app.

1. A Splash screen
2. Then MainActivity

   - GetSharedPerf
   - if(sharedpref == empty or null) {
   - Open activity --> Login Activity
   - }
3. else { Stay on MainActivity }

My Question is After Successful login I need to add new user

--> add new user User Id in Shared pref & Switch between Users in MainActivity

Note: Simply I need gmail app model for add multiple user ac and switch between users inbox...

[image: Add(Join) new user to current Navigation]

Comment: Is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Check the link... that i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to allow multiple users to log in at same time. then you should use the sqlite database for storing the user login details.

after successful login store the data to table. then add another user data from main activity. and so on you can allow as many users you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Is there any other simple way like shared pref?  Any sample code or link?

Comment: it's not advisable but what you can do is store another value as "user_count" in which add the number of users logging in. and the accordingly you can get the values for "user_id_1","user_id_2" ..."user_id_n"

Comment: I have sqlite insert, update, delete code but how to handle users switch and get corresponding user stored values or get selected user

Comment: you can keep the selected user's uid in sharedpref and accordingly you can get the data from database.or you can add column in user table as 'is_selected' which you will update to 1 after selection. upvote if helped!

Comment: Thanks i got the idea but is there any sample code or link? plz share

Comment: you can refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: i cant upvote bcaz it shows "Once you earn a total of 15 reputation , your votes will change the publicly displayed" :(

Comment: it makes count it just doesn't display publicly.. anyways. Thanks.!

Comment: I referred ur link but it shows general curd operation only... need my model sample code (Sry am basically a lazy devleoper :) )

Comment: sorry dude. cant generate the exact same code. you are developer and you have to write your own code which suits your requirements. you can do that. good luck. drop comment here if need any help.

Comment: Google says There are millon billon trillon lines of sourcode available on internet! but for me nothing here? OMG..... anyway thanks for the advice... i try my best....